# How to locate the checkbox at the center of a button vertically

Tags: android

I have a checkbox implemented in xml and locate the checkbox xml on top of a button.

custom_checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true"
android:drawable="@xml/checked" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
 android:drawable="@xml/checked" />
<item android:drawable="@xml/unchecked" />
</selector>
```

checked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:startColor="#ffff0000" android:endColor="#ff000000" android:angle="270"/>
<stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#ffc0c0c0" />
<size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

unchecked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:startColor="#ff585858" android:endColor="#ff000000" android:angle="270"/>
<stroke android:width="4px" android:color="#ffc0c0c0" />
<size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

The checkbox is located on top of a button as shown in the attached image. How can I center the checkbox vertically in the xml? 
Thanks

EDIT 1: My layout xml is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SettingActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:background ="@color/green_gradient"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/activation" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/overspeed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background ="@color/green_gradient"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:text="@string/overspeed" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/overspeedcheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@xml/custom_checkbox"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/autoupdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/overspeed"
        android:layout_below="@+id/overspeed"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background ="@color/green_gradient"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/autoupdate" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/autoupdatecheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@xml/custom_checkbox"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/movementdetect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/autoupdate"
        android:background ="@color/green_gradient"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/movement" />
     <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/movementdetectcheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@xml/custom_checkbox"/>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/geofence"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/movementdetect"
        android:background ="@color/green_gradient"
        android:layout_below="@+id/movementdetect"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/geofence" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/geofencecheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@xml/custom_checkbox"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/passwordchange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:background ="@color/green_gradient"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/changepassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/passwordreset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:background ="@color/green_gradient"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/passwordreset" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/timezonechange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:background ="@color/green_gradient"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/timezonechange" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/timezonecheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@xml/custom_checkbox"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/simnumberchange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:background ="@color/green_gradient"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/simnumberchange" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/authorizenumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:background ="@color/green_gradient"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/authorizenumber" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/authorizenumbercheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@xml/custom_checkbox"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkstatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:background ="@color/green_gradient"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/checkstatus" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Not an xml expert, but how do you define the anchor point of the check boxes?  It looks like the top edge is at the center of the button and that if you define the anchor point to be (.5,.5) it would put it where you asked for it.

Comment: Now, i implemented it in the program as ckeckbox.topMargin = (int) (button.topMargin + (int)(button.height-checkboxHeightPixels)/2);

Comment: My layout xml is updated